# google-services.json implications on FCM due to changes for Phone based auth & SHA-1 certificate

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

At present, I am in the development.

In the past I have incorporated FCM in my app with all due procedures given at - 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Things were working as expected, until today I have realized in my App, Cloud messages are not getting delivered.

What is changed wrt Firebase for my app recently (just in last 5-6 days) is - I have incorporated Firebase Phone auth (OTP) based authentication & SHA-1 certificate is generated.
I have also noted google-services.json : currently I have downloaded & the one I was using until now are different in few aspects.

My question remains, if things have changed, why I havent got any Message received or notification failures. Irony is, while sending FCM message at the server, I am not getting any failure. May be message is sent successfully ?

Another important aspect - I am sending FCM messages from PHP page on the Web server. My thought process leading me to a belief; as I have generated SHA-1 certificate, it is applicable to devices. So between FCM server & handheld device a trust is established with the help of SHA-1 encryption. But, since real FCM message is sent from my PHP page running on the Web server then, I suppose there is no trust established between the both for that server key I have procured for FCM. Hence, message may not be getting delivered to intended recipient. Is this thought process, correct ?

I am yet to test, but is there a relation of new google-services.json file with possibility of FCM to be working ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this hard way, but its worth sharing with all.

I have created simple FCM app. There I have verified with the same code I could have noifications reaching to target device.
Then I have integrated Firebase Phone Auth. Same... I could have notifications reaching to target device.

So this test concluded there must be some difference in settings the way both the apps are setup.
In the original app I was using - 
App gradle - 
firebase-auth:11.0.0
firebase-core:11.0.0
firebase-messaging:10.2.6
Project gradle - 
google-services:3.0.0

Now, in the new App I have developed today - 
App gradle - 
firebase-auth:11.0.0
firebase-core:11.0.0
firebase-messaging:11.0.0
Project gradle - 
google-services:3.1.0

So in the original App gradle configs I have changed the settings to match with the one I have recently developed. Then it worked like a bliss.

My learning through this is, if any of the Firebase library you are using the most recent, you should elevate the libraries for remaining firebase components.
As I have recently incorporated Firebase Phone Auth, hence used firebase-auth:11.0.0, but did not pay much attention to firebase-messaging.
At least I have not come across any of the documentation which asks to elevate library versions. If anyone from Google-Firebase reading this post, I request them to include this part in documentation.